# Run sudo command for executable within script

Tags: python, linux, shell, executable

I have found various answers around StackOverflow and elsewhere addressing this question, however, none of the answers provided have solved my issue.

I have tried `echo 018020 | underclock.sh` as well as the `sudo visudo` method. None of the above mentioned have worked. Even with `michallal ALL = NOPASSWD: /home/michalall/PycharmProjects/Mining/underclock.sh` I still get the following message - `sudo no tty present and no askpass program specified`:

Here's my code:

```
import os

ubu_path = '/home/michalall'
os_path = ubu_path
project_path = os_path + '/PycharmProjects/Mining/'

os.system('chmod +x ' + project_path + 'nvidia_settings')
os.system('cd ' + project_path + 'nvidia_settings/')

os.system('sudo ' + project_path + 'underclock.sh')

os.system('echo 018020 | underclock.sh')
```

**EDIT:**

When I run:

```
os.system('underclock.sh')

os.system('echo 018020 | underclock.sh')

os.system('echo 018020 | sudo -S underclock.sh')
```

I get the following output respectively:

```
sh: 1: underclock.sh: not found.

sudo no tty present and no askpass program specified

sudo no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Comment: Have you tried running your python script under `root` user?

Comment: You should generally avoid invoking `sudo` inside a script. Instead, let the user invoke `sudo` on your script if they want to elevate its privileges. Scripts should just work with whatever privileges they already have.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I agree. The only time I've had an issue like this was when my script was executing things requiring root permissions on a remote machine via SSH.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, can you explain? If the script requires sudo to run, what is the point of giving the user the option to run it without sudo? What is the benefit to having every command be done with sudo instead of just the few that require it?

Comment: Embedding a `sudo` command partway through the script means the script could partially execute, then attempt to run `sudo` and fail. `sudo` is intended to be an interactive tool. It may have difficulty prompting for a password in the middle of a script, as seen in the question. Having the user invoke `sudo` explicitly front loads the privilege escalation. The user may want to pass options to `sudo`, such as `-A` to pop up a graphical password prompt or `-u` to switch to a more privileged but still non-root user.

Comment: Another consideration is that good scripts have predictable input and output so they can be used in pipelines. `sudo` isn't designed for scriptability: sometimes it prompts you, sometimes it doesn't. And when it does prompt, it interacts directly with the terminal rather than stdin/stdout/stderr. What if there is no terminal (see question)?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `echo <password> | sudo -S <cmd>`, so that `sudo` can read password from standard input instead of a terminal device.